# Sample source for MVC, EF, WCF ,Repository and UOW pattern

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, entity-framework, repository-pattern

I want to start a MVC project, can you please guide me if you have any sample source available which could be suitable for medium scale application?

I want something with MVC with EF,WCF,Repository and Unit of work pattern included. please suggest.

Also please advise is this a good structure(MVC with EF,WCF,Repository and Unit of work pattern) which I can use for creating MVC application? Also, later I have to make this application to work as mobile application too.

Comment: Have you looked at [http://www.asp.net/mvc](http://www.asp.net/mvc)?

Comment: EF, WCF, Repository, UOW: http://ludwigstuyck.wordpress.com/2013/03/07/a-reference-architecture-part-11/. You would call the services from within your controllers from within your ASP.NET MVC project.

Comment: Unit of work? EF use it inside it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the source code from Chapter 24 of [Programming Entity Framework, 2nd Edition](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596807252.do)

It's available for free here:

2nd ed: Chapter 27 
[ASP.NET WebForms and MVC Apps using POCOs & repositories from chapter 24](http://learnentityframework.com/LearnEntityFramework/downloads/#2ed) (C#, added 10/3/2010)

I think it covers EF, UoW, MVC and Repository pattern.

It will certainly make more sense if you read the book, but exploring the code might help you.